# Is Cordova for Android broken on the Mac?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to get started with Cordova (on Mac Sierra): https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted

I already have Android Studio (Version 2.2.2) installed and I'm using Android SDK 24.

So I follow the Getting Started instructions...

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova --version
```

I have Cordova 6.4.0.

```
cordova create hello
cd hello
cordova platform add android
```

This should *just work*, but I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 24].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 28.559 secs
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: /Users/richardeng/hello/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/richardeng/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: /Users/richardeng/hello/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
```

So what is it with the Mac???

Comment: Did you try updating the SDK directly (along with accepting the license agreement)?

Comment: @Morrison Chang - yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to Setup your PATH environment variable on Mac OS [like is explained here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/getting-started/android/#3a-setup-your-path-environment-variable-on-mac-os).
2. If it doesn't work try to update android studio or just your sdkmanager like i explain on [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090061/how-to-fix-failed-to-install-cordova-plugin-consoleerror/45960453#45960453).
3. Anyway android studio make **his own android-sdk directory, be sure your cordova project is pointing to the same directory**.